# Select most "popular" follower for particular person. The more followers someone has, the more "popular" they are

Tags: mysql, sql

> Find most "popular" follower for a specific person. The more followers someone has, the more
>   "popular" they are.

I need SQL query to select most popular follower of particular people.

My Table - (followers)

```
id | person_id | follower_person_id
1    1            2
2    1            3
3    2            1
4    2            4
5    3            1
6    3            2
7    3            4
8    4            3
```

> For example person_id 1 has total 2 follower, person_id 2 has total 2
>   followers, person_id 3 has total 3 followers and person_id 4 has total
>   2 followers.
>
> Therefore, person_id 3 is most popular follower for person_id 1, 
>   person_id 1 is most popular follower for person_id 2 and so on...

Here is my query but its not working...

```
SELECT follower_person_id FROM followers f where f.person_id = 1 group by f.follower_person_id having max(select count(*) from followers where person_id = f.follower_person_id)
```

Comment: `mysql` or `oracle`?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase you question: you actually want to find the most popular follower *per* person.

Comment: I want to find a most popular follower for a specific person. And the person who has more follower we define as popular follower for that specific person. @ Giorgos Betsos

Comment: 1 expected output for the question will help in analysis.

Comment: @Biswabid person_id 3 is most popular follower for person_id 1

Comment: Please update your question to include the new information in these comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the number of followers for each person:

```
SELECT person_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM followers
GROUP BY person_id
```

**Output:**

```
person_id cnt
-------------
1         2
2         2
3         3
4         1
```

Using the above query as a derived table you can get the number of followers for follower for each person (sounds a bit complicated!):

```
SELECT t1.person_id, t1.follower_person_id, t2.cnt
FROM followers AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT person_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM followers
   GROUP BY person_id 
) AS t2  ON t1.follower_person_id = t2.person_id
```

**Output:**

```
person_id, follower_person_id, cnt
------------------------------------
1,         2,                  2
1,         3,                  3
2,         1,                  2
2,         4,                  1
3,         1,                  2
3,         2,                  2
3,         4,                  1
4,         3,                  3
```

Since you are looking for just a *specific* person, you can use a `WHERE` clause in the above query:

```
SELECT t1.person_id, t1.follower_person_id, t2.cnt
FROM followers AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT person_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM followers
   GROUP BY person_id 
) AS t2  ON t1.follower_person_id = t2.person_id
WHERE t1.person_id = 1
ORDER BY t2.cnt DESC LIMIT 1
```

`ORDER BY` with `LIMIT` will give you the most popular person the specific person is following.

**Output:**

```
person_id, follower_person_id, cnt
-----------------------------------
1,         3,                  3
```

**Note:** You can generalize the output of the second query using variables to get the most popular person each person follows (this is a greatest-per-group problem).

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks

Comment: Can you help me for this question? [Here is link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43285818/6939715)

Answer (score 1):

could you be looking for something like

```
SELECT person_id,COUNT(person_id) as followerCount FROM followers 
GROUP BY person_id ORDER BY COUNT(person_id) DESC;
```

Comment: adding a Min would select the first follower's id something like

SELECT person_id,COUNT(person_id) as follower,MIN(follower_person_id) follower_id FROM followers GROUP BY
person_id ORDER BY COUNT(person_id) DESC;

Answer (score 1):

This will arbitrarily pick one of the most popular followers if there is a tie for a single person, but it does give the desired result.

```
SELECT
  person_id,
  (
    SELECT
      _f.follower_person_id
    FROM
      followers _f
    WHERE
      _f.person_id = f.person_id
    GROUP BY
      _f.follower_person_id
    ORDER BY
      COUNT( _f.follower_person_id ) DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
FROM
  followers f
GROUP BY
  person_id
```

Working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd813/14)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do group by person id not by follower id, should take follower_id count .

```
SELECT person_id ,count(follower_person_id) FROM followers f group by f.person_id 
having count(follower_person_id)=(select max(f_cnt ) from
(select count(follower_person_id) f_cnt from followers group by person_id))
```

If there are 2 persons with same number of most popular then it will return those 2 person with same count

Answer (score 0):

@Parth Can you try this smaller version, i think this is small and simple to understand

```
With temp as 
(

  select a.id, a.person_id, count(b.follower_person_id) as  follower from 
  TableName a
  inner join  TableName b on a.person_id=b.follower_person_id
  Group by a.person_id
)
 select top 1 * from temp order by follower_person_id desc
```