# Returns a list of all users, paired with their most "popular" follower. The more followers someone has, the more "popular" they are

Tags: mysql, sql

> Find most "popular" follower for the persons. The more followers someone has, the more
>   "popular" they are.

I need SQL query to select most popular follower of people.

My Table - (followers)

```
id | person_id | follower_person_id
1    1            2
2    1            3
3    2            1
4    2            4
5    3            1
6    3            2
7    3            4
8    4            3
```

> Person_id 1 has total 2 follower (person_id 2, person_id 3), person_id
>   2 has total 2 followers (person_id 1, person_id 4), person_id 3 has
>   total 3 followers (person_id 1, person_id 2, person_id 4)and person_id
>   4 has total 1 followers (person_id 3).
>
> Therefore, person_id 3 is most popular follower for person_id 1,
>   person_id 1 is most popular follower for person_id 2, person_id 1 (or
>   person_id 2) is most popular follower for person_id 3 and person_id 3
>   is most popular for person_id 4.

Here is query...

```
SELECT t1.person_id, t1.follower_person_id, t2.cnt
FROM followers AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT person_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM followers
   GROUP BY person_id 
) AS t2  ON t1.follower_person_id = t2.person_id
WHERE t1.person_id = 1
ORDER BY t2.cnt DESC LIMIT 1
```

Above query Output is

```
person_id, follower_person_id, cnt
-----------------------------------
1,         3,                  3
```

[Here is explanation of above query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43270481/6939715)

> this query only work for find popular person for a specific person but
>   I want to find a paired with their most "popular" follower for all person.

SO output should be like

```
person_id, follower_person_id, cnt
-----------------------------------
1,         3,                  3
2,         1,                  2
3,         1,                  2
4,         3,                  3
```

Now I have another `person table`

```
id | name 
1    John         
2    Ali         
3    Rohn         
4    Veronica
```

Now I want to convert this id to person name.

> Final Output shoud like

```
person_name, follower_person_name, cnt
--------------------------------------
John,        Rohn,                 3
Ali,         John,                 2
Rohn,        John,                 2
Veronica,    Rohn,                 3
```

I need sql query to get this data.

Comment: how do you define the "their most "popular" follower for all person." ... please explain clearly ..

Comment: Person_id 1 has total 2 follower (person_id 2, person_id 3), person_id 2 has total 2 followers (person_id 1, person_id 4), person_id 3 has total 3 followers (person_id 1, person_id 2, person_id 4)and person_id 4 has total 1 followers (person_id 3).

Therefore, person_id 3 is most popular follower for person_id 1, person_id 1 is most popular follower for person_id 2, person_id 1 (or person_id 2) is most popular follower for person_id 3 and person_id 3 is most popular for person_id 4. @scaisEdge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT person_name, follower_name, cnt
FROM (
   SELECT person_name, follower_name, cnt,
          @rn := IF(@pname = person_name, @rn + 1,
                    IF(@pname := person_name, 1, 1)) AS rn
   FROM (
      SELECT t3.name AS person_name, t4.name AS follower_name, t2.cnt
      FROM followers AS t1
      JOIN (
         SELECT person_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
         FROM followers
         GROUP BY person_id 
      ) AS t2  ON t1.follower_person_id = t2.person_id
      JOIN person AS t3 ON t1.person_id = t3.id
      JOIN person AS t4 ON t1.follower_person_id = t4.id   
   ) AS x
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @pname := '') AS vars
   ORDER BY person_name, cnt DESC) AS v
wHERE v.rn = 1;
```

**Output:**

```
person_name follower_name   cnt
--------------------------------
John        Rohn            3
Veronica    Rohn            3
Ali         John            2
Rohn        Ali             2
```

The query uses variables in order to get the greatest-per-group record.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/MYP90624)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.name, p2.name, t2.cnt
FROM followers AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT person_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM followers
   GROUP BY person_id 
) AS t2  ON t1.follower_person_id = t2.person_id
join person p1 on t1.person_id=person.id
join person p2 on t1.follower_person_id=person.id
ORDER BY t2.cnt DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: No, this one is not working. there is an error. If I write `join person p1 on t1.person_id=p1.id
join person p2 on t1.follower_person_id=p2.id`. then it works. but its does not give expected result

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can combine it with a few code on your language of choice
Try the following query to sort followers from highest to lower and get the name of your second column:

```
select f.person_id, p.name
from followers f 
inner join person p on p.id=f.person_id
group by f.person_id order by count(f.follower_person_id) desc
```

For each output id (lets call it `FIXED_ID_FROM_PREVIOUS_QUERY` you try to get the persons he is following and create columns 1 and 3

```
select p.name, count(f.follower_person_id)
from followers f 
inner join person p on p.id=f.person_id 
inner join person pf on pf.id=f.follower_person_id where 
f.person_id in (select person_id from followers where follower_person_id=FIXED_ID_FROM_PREVIOUS_QUERY)
group by f.person_id order by count(f.follower_person_id) desc
```